# "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." When trying to access Exchange via Webdav

Tags: exchange-server, webdav, http-status-code-401

I asked another question earlier about a 400 error. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099557/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request-when-trying-to-access-e)

While waiting for responses, I tried a few other things and have now come across another unhelpful error. ("The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.").

I am trying to connect to http://mailserver/owa/. When I paste this URL into my browser, and type my credentials, I can get logged in just fine. When I try to connect with the same credentials through WebDav, I get the 401 error. How do the same credentials work one way, but not another way?

I tried using the authenticate method found here: http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/

I still get the same 401.

This seems like it should be so straightforward, yet all I can find out there are forums of people with the same problem. Nobody can provide and answer or working example. Has anyone actually ever been able to do this successfully before!?

Comment: I'm having the same errors. Did you ever find an answer?